# What are the security ramifications of indirectly executing application-defined/user-defined functions in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, security, tcl

I have some questions/concerns related to the "potential security vulnerability" when using functions, as described in the Tcl interface to SQLite library documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html#function.

> -directonly
>
> This option restricts the function to only be usable by direct top-level SQL statement. The function will not be accessible to triggers, views, CHECK constraints, generated columns, or index expressions. This option is recommended for all application-defined SQL functions, and is highly recommended for any SQL function that has side effects or that reveals internal state of the application.
>
> Security Warning: Without this switch, an attacker might be able to change the schema of a database file to include the new function inside a trigger or view or CHECK constraint and thereby trick the application into running the function with parameters of the attacker's choosing. Hence, if the new function has side effects or reveals internal state about the application and the -directonly option is not used, that is a potential security vulnerability.

I'm having some trouble understanding how this vulnerability is exploited; that may be due to my concerns/expectations being influenced by what I am trying to accomplish (that is detailed later in the question).

A thorough description of how this works or a code example of how it can be exploited would be very helpful to me.

It would also be useful to have an explanation of what risks are presented:

1. Does it allow compromising a host?
2. Does it allow manipulating the database?
3. Does it allow getting data from the database?
   I assume for points 1 and 2 here, that would be possible if the function has side effects facilitating that; e.g. if a function existed that executed `rm -rf` on the host, then this vulnerability could do that.  However, if the function does not do that and does not manipulate the database, are points 1 and 2 still risks from this vulnerability?
   Regarding point 3, I don't understand how it allows getting data that shouldn't be available?

It seems to me that this vulnerability relies on the application using a database file supplied by a malicious actor, that uses triggers to run functions that should normally not be run by untrusted actors; is that correct?

In that case, would this vulnerability be mitigated by the following approach?

1. Open the untrusted database file(s) with trusted_schema = off.
2. Copy the contents of tables to the equivalent tables of a database that can be trusted, i.e. one created by the database itself.

Regarding my specific use case:
I am trying to create a flexible modding system for a game; the database is going to be following the [entity-attribute-value model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

I had the thought that it would be helpful if modders could define constraints for attributes.  To this end, I came up with the following approach:

1. Create an interpreter to manage the database, safe interpreter(s) and other stuff requiring trusted capabilities.
2. Create a safe interpreter for modder's to script in.
3. Create/load a database that will use this entity-attribute-value model.
4. The key part - add trigger(s) to the database, for when the attribute table(s) are manipulated, that delegate constraint-checking to procs defined in the safe interpreter.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This line continues for Tcl, but is a single line for 'sh' \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}


package require sqlite3

proc delegate {id type value} {
    set proc_name "is_valid_$type"

    # If no proc has been defined to delegate to, automatically succeed.
    if {[safe_interp eval "info proc $proc_name"] eq ""} {
        return
    }

    set failed [catch {
        safe_interp eval "$proc_name $id $type $value"
    } error_msg]

    if {$failed} {
        puts "delegate to: $proc_name\
            \nwith args:\
            \n  id: $id\
            \n  type: $type\
            \n  value: $value\
            \nfailed with error msg: $error_msg"
    }

    # Used by the trigger to determine whether to rollback.
    return [expr {!$failed}]
}

proc insert_attribute {type value} {
    db eval {
        insert into attribute (type, value) values(:type, :value);
    }
}

interp create -safe safe_interp
interp alias safe_interp insert_attribute {} insert_attribute
safe_interp eval {
    proc is_valid_t1 {id type value} {
        error "error: is invalid for some reason I guess?"
    }
    proc is_valid_t2 {id type value} {}
}

sqlite3 db -create true ""

db function delegate delegate

db eval {
    create table attribute(
        id integer primary key,
        type varchar not null,
        value varchar not null 
    );
}

db eval {
    create trigger delegate_on_attribute_insert
    after insert on attribute
    begin
        select case (select delegate(new.id, new.type, new.value))
        when false then
            raise(rollback, 'delegate failed, rolling back')
        end;
    end;
}

# Fails because attribute type t1 has a proc defined
# that checks for validity, and that proc is defined to always
# give an error.
if {[catch {safe_interp eval insert_attribute t1 v1} msg]} {
    puts "msg: $msg"
}

# Succeeds because attribute type t2's validity-checking proc
# always succeeds.
if {[catch {safe_interp eval insert_attribute t2 v1} msg]} {
    puts "msg: $msg"
}

# Succeeds because attribute type t3's has
# no validity-checking proc so nothing makes it fail.
if {[catch {safe_interp eval insert_attribute t3 v1} msg]} {
    puts "msg: $msg"
}

puts "attributes: [db eval {
    select * from attribute
}]"
```

This gives the output:

```
delegate to: is_valid_t1 
with args: 
  id: 1 
  type: t1 
  value: v1 
failed with error msg: error: is invalid for some reason I guess?
msg: delegate failed, rolling back
attributes: 1 t2 v1 2 t3 v1
```

In this use case, what dangers are there in running with either trusted_schema = on, or with the delegate function marked as innocuous?

Comment: The wording on the option's docs comes from the wording on the equivalent flag in the SQLite C API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vulnerability comes from the possibility that you might have functions defined that allow a database to manipulate the world outside of itself (e.g., by sending an email). That's very powerful and useful when combined with especially triggers, but *if* the DB can be manipulated outside your program by an attacker, they can cause those functions to be called in ways you didn't expect. *That doesn't mean this will definitely happen!* Deployment scenarios can easily prevent it, perhaps by ensuring that nobody else can run their code on the computer or that only the authorised user can write to the DB, but the SQLite engine doesn't know this so it is rightly cautious.

The caution it takes is by making places in the schema (the place where SQL is stored in the DB) be unable to run dangerous functions by default. That's trigger programs, check constraints, view definitions, etc. Marking a function as direct only disqualifies it from being run in those situations; it has to be directly in the SQL code that you have in your program. (If you do want to use world-changing functions in trigger programs, just don't mark them as direct only, as they have to be re-registered with every connection anyway.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I intend to allow users to manipulate and query the database, but not change the world; they would be provided functions that run SQL code, but would not be allowed to write their own SQL code.  Also, as in my example, they would be able to write Tcl code that would be called by specific triggered SQL functions, but the Tcl code would be in a safe interpreter.  So my interpretation of what you've told me is that this should be safe, assuming my program also doesn't do anything unsafe with the data it ingests from the database.  Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Also, if I understand correctly, it would be ok/safe to use user-provided database files directly, instead of copying their tables into my own database?  I would just have to run it with trusted_schema = off, and mark any function I wanted to allow to be run by triggers as -innocuous?

Comment: That's a tricky judgement call. It *might* be OK?

Comment: Fair enough.  Security is such fun!  Thank you for all your help!